# Scala not found: value x when unpacking returned tuple

Tags: scala, tuples

I've seen this kind of code on countless websites yet it doesn't seem to compile:

```
def foo(): (Int, Int) = {
        (1, 2)
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val (I, O) = foo()
}
```

It fails on the marked line, reporting:

- not found: value I
- not found: value O

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: It's because they're capital letters. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727612/scalas-tuple-unwrapping-nuance. `val (i, o) = foo` will work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the use of upper case letters `I` and `O` in your pattern match. You should try to replace it by lowercase letters `val (i, o) = foo()`. The [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) states that a value definition can be expanded to a pattern match. For example the definition `val x :: xs = mylist` expands to the following (cf. p. 39):

```
val x$ = mylist match { case x :: xs => {x, xs} }
val x = x$._1
val xs = x$._2
```

In your case, the value definition `val (i, o) = foo()` is expanded in a similar way. However, the language specification also states, that a pattern match contains lower case letters (cf. p. 114):

> A variable pattern x is a simple identiﬁer which starts with a lower
>   case letter.

Comment: spent 2 hours looking for this answer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

As per Scala [naming convention](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html),

> Method, Value and variable names should be in camelCase with the first
>   letter lower-case:

Your `I, O` are pattern variables. However, you have to use caution when defining them. By convention, Scala expects the pattern variables to start with a lowercase letter and
expects constants to start with an uppercase letter. So, the code will not compile.